# How to make a bound DataGrid have empty rows without reflecting in binding source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that is bound to a data source via `ItemsSource`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" ...

private ObservableCollection<Data> myData = null;
public ObservableCollection<Data> MyData
{
    get
    {
        if (myData == null)
            myData = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

        return myData;
    }
}
```

These are my requirements.

1. This datagrid needs to have several empty rows (without any data) when it first loads, and these empty rows will always be there at the bottom of the datagrid even after other data are loaded later.
2. These empty rows must not be reflected at the source collection (`MyData`). The reason being the source collection is used by other parts of the program.
3. The empty rows allow user to add in new "template" `Data` via **doubleclicking** on any of the empty rows; "template" here means a `Data` object with pre-defined set of attributes (non-empty, though).
4. This project is not following MVVM so it is fine to break any or even all the rules of MVVM.

I know the requirements may look stupid, but these are the requirements that I need to fulfill, regardless stupid or not. I would prefer to do it in a more proper way, but I am tied to these requirements and I could do nothing.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

### Edit

Hmm, I actually figured it out one solution myself. I made another property that mirrors the original property, by subscribing to original ObservableCollection's `CollectionChanged` event.

```
private static object _emptyData = new object();
private ObservableCollection<object> myClonedData =
    new ObservableCollection<object>() { _emptyData, _emptyData, _emptyData };
public ObservableCollection<object> MyClonedData
{
    get
    {
        return myClonedData;
    }
    private set
    {
        if (myClonedData != value)
        {
            myClonedData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyClonedData");
        }
    }
}

private void MyData_OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        foreach (var newitem in e.NewItems)
        {
            MyClonedData.Insert(MyClonedData.Count - 3, newitem);
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("MyClonedData");
    }
    else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        foreach (var newitem in e.NewItems)
        {
            MyClonedData.Remove(newitem);
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("MyClonedData");
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Data> MyData
{
    get
    {
        if (myData == null)
            myData = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

        return myData;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != myData)
        {
            if (myData != null)
                myData.CollectionChanged -= MyData_OnCollectionChanged;
            value.CollectionChanged += MyData_OnCollectionChanged;

            myData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyData");

            MyClonedData = new ObservableCollection<object>()
                { _emptyData, _emptyData, _emptyData };
        }
    }
}
```

Probably not very elegant considering how much I am using setters to do stuff, but it works. I am still looking for better alternatives out there.

### Edit 2

I rephrased some of my requirements as they were not too clear. Also to answer Kylo regarding my own solution in previous edit. In that solution, I made another property (`MyClonedData` collection) which my datagrid could bind with, and that collection is a clone of the original `MyData` collection. This way, the empty rows are added through generic `Object` instance, but are added only to the cloned collection. This way, my original collection is untouched, so other parts of my program is able to access and process it.

Comment: still code doesn't look perfect. How are the empty rows that present in "MyClonedData" collection cause it's bound to grid, are filtered out if you are assign that collection to your original collection (MyData)?

Answer (score 0):

Change your property `MyData` `get` method like this:

```
 private ObservableCollection<Data> myData = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Data> MyData
    {
        get
        {
            if (myData == null)
                myData = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
            if (myData != null)
            {
                myData = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(myData.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name)));
                //If Class Data has property Name
                //Additional consitions also can be added in where clause
            }
            return myData;
        }
    }
```

But I recommend you better filter out this collection when you needed it via a method instead.

Comment: Hmm, how does changing that gives me the empty rows?

Comment: @Jai cause the next time you'll try to get the value of property "MyData", the get method will filter out blank rows from the "myData" field using the clause written. try getting the count of collection after there are many empty rows on datagrid.

Comment: @Jai Totally depends on your requirement, if needed then from grid or if you want you can add empty objects in your collection. let me know I'll update the answer for convenience.

Comment: @Jai how do you want them>

Comment: Just curious, is the list of requirements that I wrote really unclear?

Comment: @Jai Yes, point 1 is highly ambiguous how do you want it. You said you want several empty rows. you didn't specify you want them by default to display on datagrid or you just want to keep adding them on user interaction neglecting the fact how previous rows are. and point 3 also "The empty rows allow user to add in new "template" Data via" what exactly do you mean? Considering the fact you are working after binding ItemSource of DataGrid, you know every change will get reflected to source, even empty objects.

Comment: @Jai also in your edit you are adding every new item to your another collection, don;t you want to check it's empty first. or empty mean something else here?